# Delete or drop Mongodb database on server ecs2 through another server shell file

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I am on Linux Server. My MongoDB Database is stored there. Now if I want to delete the database from another machine lets say my development machine, then for that I created the steps but not working for me.

create a delete.sh file

```
#!usr/bin/env mongo
#instance Ip assume:
mongo 12.122.12.12:27017/tempDatabase --eval "db.dropDatabase"
```

But I am unable to delete the Database. Any idea that where I have done mistakes. Any interaction is really appreciated

Comment: run command for this is "sudo ./delete.sh"

Comment: Is it working? What's the error you're getting?